# Is there a way to await multiple await calls within a async function?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

this function reads all my Movie documents and parses certain attributes; creating new documents in my Person Collection.

[image]

ERROR MESSAGE:------------------------------------------------

await Person.create({
^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Questions here should not contain code in images.  This makes it hard for people to copy/paste code into answers, it makes it impossible for the code and comments to get indexed, it makes it harder for some accessibility, etc...  Please past code as text and formatted properly.  As an example, if I wanted to show you the proper way to write your code, I'd have to manually retype everything you have in that image which is enormously inefficient.  You don't want to make it hard for people to offer you complete and thorough answers.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `Promise.all()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
It allows you to wait for multiple promises.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
As pointed out by @jfriend00, [Array.forEach expects a synchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#forEach_expects_a_synchronous_function), and does not handle Promises / async / await. To use async & await, you should replace all your uses of `Array.forEach` with a for-loop:

```js
for (const movie of movieObj) { ... }
```

As for awaiting multiple async calls, if you want those calls to really be asynchronous, rather than awaiting each individual call, you can await on the *array* of async calls using `Promise.all`. Since it accepts an array of promises, you'll want to use `Array.map`. You could do this for example:

```js
await Promise.all(arrayWriters.map((el) => Person.create(...)));
```

Comment: But, `.forEach()` is not promise-aware, so using `await` in its callback will NOT pause the loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right about that, good catch. Instead of `.forEach()`, OP should rely on:
`for (let movie of movieObj) { await ... }`

Comment: Yes, and your answer would be a better answer if you modified it to not show the use of `.forEach()` and to show the user of a `for` loop.